# mongoose when res json is called, it is being executed twice instead of once

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am having a really hard time, understanding why it is executing res.json() twice.

```
// GET - Get MY Applications
router.get('/myApplications', function(req, res) {
    var taskid;
    var app_length;
    Application.find({ email: req.session.email}, function(err, application){
        app_length = application.length;
        var getMyTasks = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < app_length; i++){
            taskid = application[i].task_id;
            Task.findOne({task_id:application[i].task_id}, function(err, result){
                if(i = app_length - 1){
                    console.log("final");
                    res.json({getMyTasks});
                    console.log("after final");
                }
                else if(err){
                    return res.send(err);
                }
                else if(!result){
                    Application.findOneAndUpdate({$and:[{email:req.session.email, task_id:taskid}]},{$set:{status:1}},{new:true}, function(err, myapp){
                        getMyTasks.push(myapp);
                    });
                }
                else if(result){
                    getMyTasks.push(result);
                }
            }); 
        }
    });
});
```

by executing it twice it is giving me the famous `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

This is the exact error:

```
final                                                                                                                            
after final                                                                                                                      
final                                                                                                                            
events.js:160                                                                                                                    
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event                                                                                       
      ^                                                                                                                          

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

We can clearly see that res.json is being executed twice.

this error is occuring where I have:

`if ( i = app.length - 1){}`

Answer (score 1):

A single equals is assignment, so

```
if(i = app_length - 1)
```

is true multiple times, which means

```
res.json({getMyTasks});
```

gets executed multiple times. It needs to be

```
if(i === app_length - 1)
```

Comment: jeeeez how did I miss that.

Comment: How was that not crashing the app?

Comment: I know right. But I feel like I have much more problems. The bigger problem I have right now, is that I lose my values outside of my query. Which I dont really know how to fix. I got to do some research about this. but if you have a better implementation that what I currently have. please help. @Darkrum

Comment: @user3450754 I recommend using promises with Mongoose instead of callbacks. It's much cleaner and easier to work with IMO.

Comment: @user3450754 Sorry can't be of help. I ditched mongodb when i found out that the drivers logic is done on your own application. I switched to postgres and never looked back.